# NameError: name 'form' is not defined (Python3)

Tags: python, error-handling

Basically the `main` method takes user input, checks it and calls the `first` method if the user doesn't enter `quit`.

The `first` method checks the first section of the input and calls one of the other methods depending on what the user enters. This is the point I get an error; when the `first` method calls the `form` method, for example, I get an `NameError: name 'form' is not defined` exception. I'm a little confused about this since I've defined each method and they're all spelt correctly, also when I call the `quit` method it works perfectly fine.

Main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        for line in sys.stdin:
                s = line.strip()
                if not s: break
                if (str(s) == "quit"): quit()
                elif (str(s) == "quit") == False:
                        a = s.split()
                        print(a)
                        if (len(a) is 2): first(a)
                        elif (len(a) is 3): first(a)
                        else: print("Invalid Input. Please Re-enter.")
```

First method:

```
def first(a = list()):
        word = a[0]

        if word == "ls":
                ls(a[1])           
        elif word == "format":
                form(a[1])
        elif word == "reconnect":
                reconnect(a[1])
        elif word == "mkfile":
                mkfile(a[1])
        elif word == "mkdir":
                mkdir(a[1])
        elif word == "append":
                append(a[1], a[2])                               
        elif word == "delfile":
                delfile(a[1])
        elif word == "deldir":
                deldir(a[1])
        else:
                print("Invalid Prompt. Please Re-enter.")
```

Other methods (these are all called from the first method):

```
def reconnect(one = ""):
        print("Reconnect")

def ls(one = ""):
        print("list")

def mkfile(one = ""):
        print("make file")

def mkdir(one = ""):
        print("make drive")

def append(one = "", two = ""):
        print("append")

def form(one = ""):
        print("format " + one)

def delfile(one = ""):
        print("delete file")

def deldir(one = ""):
        print("delete directory")

def quit():
        print("quit")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You're sure you are defining these before they are called?

Comment: Yes, I've defined all the methods in the opposite order to what I've posted. I've tried swapping the order around too.

Comment: try - form(one=a[1])

Comment: @SumanKalyan That doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

this error is because of

```
    elif word == "format":
            form(a[1])
```

python basically doesn't know what form is.

let me show you:

```
gaf@$[09:21:56]~> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> form()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'form' is not defined
>>>
```

there is two ways out

```
>>> def form():
...     pass
...
>>> form()
>>> form
<function form at 0x7f49d7f38a28>
>>>
```

or import it form some library using

```
import
```

command

also order is matters too

```
try:
    form()
except NameError:
    print('Oops name error raise above')


def form():
    print('form foo is called')

try:
    form()
except NameError:
    print('Oops name error raise below')
```

will give you

```
/home/gaf/dashboard/bin/python /home/gaf/PycharmProjects/dashboard/test.py
Oops name error raise above
form foo is called

Process finished with exit code 0
```

P.S.
take a look at pep8
your code is a mess %)
but no worries this what everybody does with first language

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you use python 2.7 or 3, but your code works with some minor changes.

```
import sys
def reconnect(one=""):
    print("Reconnect")

def ls(one=""):
    print("list")

def mkfile(one=""):
    print("make file")

def mkdir(one=""):
    print("make drive")

def append(one="", two=""):
    print("append")

def form(one=""):
    print("format " + one)

def delfile(one=""):
    print("delete file")

def deldir(one=""):
    print("delete directory")

def quit():
    print("quit")
    sys.exit(0)

def first(a=list()):
    word = a[0]

    if word == "ls":
        ls(a[1])
    elif word == "format":
        form(a[1])
    elif word == "reconnect":
        reconnect(a[1])
    elif word == "mkfile":
        mkfile(a[1])
    elif word == "mkdir":
        mkdir(a[1])
    elif word == "append":
        append(a[1], a[2])
    elif word == "delfile":
        delfile(a[1])
    elif word == "deldir":
        deldir(a[1])
    else:
        print("Invalid Prompt. Please Re-enter.")

line = raw_input("Some input please: ")  # or `input("Some...` in python 3

print(line)
s = line.strip()

if (str(s) == "quit"):
    quit()
elif (str(s) == "quit") == False:
    a = s.split()
    print(a)
    if (len(a) is 2):
        first(a)
    elif (len(a) is 3):
        first(a)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input. Please Re-enter.")
```

Test

```
 python pyprog.py 
Some input please: ls text.txt
ls text.txt
['ls', 'text.txt']
list
```

You can also try it [online](https://repl.it/D5Vy).

[image]

Comment: @GabbyFreeland please try it here https://repl.it/D5Vy You can write `format a` and it calls the form function

Comment: @GabbyFreeland I updated the question with a screenshot. Please have a look at the provided screenshot. It runs the `form` function, evidently.

Comment: Ok, that's strange. I just edited mine and when it's inside a class it doesn't work but when you get rid of the class and keep everything else the same it does work. Do you have any idea why that is?